# match multiple conditions with GNU sed

Tags: bash, perl, shell, awk, sed

I'm using sed to replace values in other bash scripts, such as:

```
somedata="$(<somefile.sh)"
somedata=`sed 's/ ==/==/g' <<< $somedata` # [space]== becomes ==
somedata=`sed 's/== /==/g' <<< $somedata` # ==[space] becomes ==
```

The same for ||, &&, !=, etc.  I think steps should be reduced with the right regex match.  The operator does not need surrounding spaces, but may have a space before and after, only before, or only after.  Is there a way to handle all of these with one sed command?

There are many other conditions not mentioned also.  The script takes more time to execute than desired.

The goal is to reduce the overall execution time so I am hoping to reduce the number of commands used with clever regex to match multiple conditions.

I'm also considering tr, awk or perl - whichever is fastest?

Comment: Spaces are allowed around `&&`, `||`, `==`, and `!=` in bash, so why go to the trouble of removing them?

Comment: `&` means `the string that matched the regexp` on the right side of a substitution, so you need to escape the `&`s in that context.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot To minify the script.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for pointing that out, I just typed it out as a sample without testing.  updated the question.

Comment: remove the escapes from the left side. &s are capture group reference characters, not regexp metacharacters. dont just escape every character you think of as "special" (because nothing in software should every be considered "special" or "new" - 2 words to NEVER use in describing software functionality!) as you can turn them into metachars by doing that. learn what each character means in its given context  as the meaning is different in each context

Comment: @EdMorton I don't follow - the following is working for me:
echo "hello && world" | sed 's/ \&\& /\&\&/g' # hello&&world

Comment: You could add a whole lot of round brackets or you could replace the escapes with square brackets and it'd "work" too IN THAT SPECIFIC CASE and you'd still just have a lot of unnecessary characters cluttering up and obfuscating your code. Try doing exactly the same thing with your other case of replacing `||` instead of `&&` though. Getting the expected output given some sample input is the starting point of writing good code, not the end point.

Comment: The point is - escape characters that have some specific metacharacter property in some specific context when you want them treated literally instead. Do not escape characters that are already literal in some specific context unless you want to enable some specific metacharacter property attributed to that character when escaped in that specific context. It'll avoid you tripping over bugs when you accidentally turn a literal into a metacharacter and make your code clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `sed`, you can use the `|` (or) operator:

```
$ sed -r 's/ *(&&|\|\|) */\1/g' <<< "foo && bar || baz"
foo&&bar||baz
```

- `*(&&|\|\|) *`: search for zero or more space followed by any of the `|` separated strings followed by zero or more space
- the matching strings are captured and output using backreference

**Edit:**

As pointed out in comments, you can use the `-E` flag with GNU sed in place of `-r`. Your command will be more portable:

```
sed -E 's/ *(\&\&|\|\|) */\1/g'
```

As GNU sed also supports `\|` alternation operator with Basic Regular Expressions, you can use it for better readability:

```
sed 's/ *\(&&\|||\) */\1/g'
```

Comment: ah yes backreferences will help me greatly in the future thank you

Comment: If you get rid of the `-r` (which you shouldn't use anyway, use `-E` instead for portability IF you need EREs which you don't in this case) then you can get rid of the escapes of the `&` and `|` characters and all you have to do is escape the capture group delimiters and you have a more concise, portable script.

Comment: @EdMorton The BREs don't include the alternation operator (the escaped `\|` is a GNU sed extension). I'm not sure that using this operator in BRE mode will be much more portable.

Comment: I see what you're saying, I missed that you needed the `|` metacharacter. I'm not sure it's just GNU sed that supports enabling ERE metacharacters with escapes, though, and `-E` will definitely enable EREs in multiple sed versions whereas `-r` only does it for GNU sed.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple sed substitutions with the `-e` flag:

```
$ echo -n "test data here" | sed -e 's/test/TEST/' \
                                 -e 's/data/HERE/' \ 
                                 -e 's/here/DATA/'
$ TEST HERE DATA
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `sedfile` (`-f` option) alongside with the `-i` option (replace in-place, no need to store in env. variable):

```
sed -i -f mysedfile somefile.sh
```

`mysedfile` may contain expressions, 1 per line

```
s/ *&& */\&\&/g
s/ *== */==/g
```

(or use the `-e` option to use several expression, but if you have a lot of them, it wil become quickly unreadable)

BTW: `-i` option creates a temporary file *within* the processed file directory, so in the end, if operation succeeds, the original file is deleted and the temporary file is *renamed* into the original file name

> When the end of the file is reached, the temporary file is renamed
>        to the output file's original name.  The extension, if supplied,
>        is used to modify the name of the old file before renaming the
>        temporary file, thereby making a backup copy(2))

so there's no I/O overhead with that option. No need at all to store in a variable.

Comment: I am intentionally storing the data in a variable to reduce execution time with all of the file read/write and tmp file creation involved with the the -i inline option.  Will a sed file or -e option still execute multiple subprocesses?  The goal is to reduce execution time by using clever regex with less commands.

Comment: multiple `-e` options won't invoke several process, that is equivalent. and see my edit for the -i option.

Comment: Yes but a temporary file is created, it's read and written to, the original file is removed, and the temporary file is renamed.  Versus the file is read, everything is done in memory, the file is written.  Also note the variables is a local one within a function.